# ELB with tcp mode and client ip stickiness

Tags: amazon-elb

I have an ELB that is used for load balancing a binary protocol (using tcp mode) with PROXY protocol enabled.

Is it possible to for a new request that comes from an already connected  source IP to be forwarded to the same back end server as the initial connection ?

I would prefer a solution working without adding another layer of load balancing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't supported.

ELB uses HTTP cookies for stickiness, so the feature is only supported in HTTP/Layer 7 mode.